# Re-use the same template for a similar job

Tags: django, filter, cron, django-templates

I ask to a client to provide us a list of documents, e.g., `['doc1', 'doc2', 'doc3', 'doc4', 'doc5']`. From this time, each 24 hours for 5 days, we send an email to the client informing him of missing documents :

```
Hello 'Mr or Ms',

We inform you that the following documents are missing to complete the request: 

'list of missing documents'
```

I'd thought that I could use a filter on that list and apply a cron job to reapply that filter every 24 hours for 5 days. The filter would only sort through the documents provided and the remaining documents to be provided by the client.

For instance, if the client has provided all the documents from the first day, then we send him a message telling him that all the documents have been delivered successfully and that he can proceed to the next step.

As I program since just some days, I need your help to resolve my problem. I'm thinking that It is not the better solution. At the beginning I thought to create five different templates with slugs `send-remaining-documents-day-one`, `send-remaining-documents-day-two`, ..., but clearly, it is not suggested I guess.

Could anyone be able to suggest a better solution than that?

Answer (score 0):

You could create only 2 templates (not sure if you need html cause you can send basic txt) like: `some_docs_missing.txt` and `all_docs_found.txt` and write a python script that will check what documents you have and what do you need then you take the difference and see what template you use.

Here is a snippet:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

# Let's say you have the 2 list of documents called: needed_docs and found_docs
missing_docs = list(set(needed_docs) - set(found_docs))
if missing_docs == []:  # All good
    message = render_to_string('all_docs_found.txt')
else:
    message = render_to_string('some_docs_missing.txt',
                               context={'missing_docs': missing_docs})

# Here send the message
```

Comment: Would you use a cron job to automate the process?

Comment: I didn't get the whole process but a cronjob seems good choice, don't forget to disable it the fifth day.